# Redis "silently" underperforming

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

We observed a very strange behavior on a redis instance that is run as managed service in AWS. Although phenomenically the instance was operational, we could observe a lot of delays and timeouts.

Diving into the monitoring dashboard, the CPU utilization graph showed a perfectly straight horizontal line at 20% of the CPU, while on average this instance usually operated at somewhere around 40-50%. It looked as if the instance had been bounded to a particular CPU limit that resulted in poor performance.

[image]

Any ideas on what might have caused such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
After searching through various resources for a possible solution, we eventually spotted the culprit in one misused Redis command. Specifically, in one of our services that relied on the particular Redis cluster for caching, a frequently executing function was using the **keys()** command to search in Redis. According to the official documentation:

```
consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance when it is executed against large databases. This command is intended for debugging and special operations, such as changing your keyspace layout. Don't use KEYS in your regular application code.
```

By removing keys(), CPU utilization instantly dropped to < 5% and never surpassed this threshold.

A bit embarassed, I am adding my reply in case someone faces a similar problem.

Tip: If you are experiencing a slow performance in Redis, use the **slowlog** command to identify slow-executing commands.